# Adding multiple nested items inside one form

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, forms, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

I have one complex problem. I need to add multiple items inside one form in ASP.NET MVC4 Application. I have three models:

Movie:

```
public class Movie
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int Duration { get; set; }
}
```

All languages in a movie:

```
public class MovieLanguages
{
    [ForeignKey("Movie")]
    public int MovieId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Language")]
    public int LanguageId { get; set; }

    public virtual Movie Movie { get; set; }
    public virtual Language Language { get; set; }
}
```

Language:

```
public class Language
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I understand how to save user's input if it is just for a Movie model with simple lines like this inside a form:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Movie.Name)
```

The problem is that user should be also able to add multiple languages for a movie inside a form (model MovieLanguages). So when the form is displayed user would have something like this:

[image]

User will have a dropdown list of languages and when he chooses a language from the list and clicks Add Language button, language will be displayed below. When he clicks Save Movie, all chosen languages should also be saved to database in table MovieLanguages. How to handle this problem when Movie id will be known only after it's stored in database? I'm not sure how to solve problem with multiple models in View and Controller when there is this one to many relation. Any ideas? :)

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is [Model Binding To A List](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx) and [Model Binding to Arrays, Lists, Collections, Dictionaries](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETWireFormatForModelBindingToArraysListsCollectionsDictionaries.aspx). The rest is tiny bit of javascript to dynamically generate required html on `Add Language` click.

Comment: Thank you but I still don't quite understand what I need to do. On that first link there is only a list with predefined number of values displayed for editing. I would be grateful if you could explain it a little bit. I don't understand how could I use that to save languages temporary and then save them to database when the movie saves.

Comment: You do not need to save languages temporarily on server - you save them in inputs in client-side html.